# Multiple criteria index match where one criteria is a does not contain

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create an index match query that contains three criteria where the first two are looking for a match but the third query is a does not contain. Is it possible to mix match conditions like this?

[image: A sample of my data]

My current match query is

=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($C2,"_"," ")&"Consumption",Prices[skuName]&Prices[type],0)

I'm trying to create a condition where I check to cells where the productName column doesn't contain Windows.

[image: The value for C2 comes from this table]

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Which column header is C2 from?

Comment: Your Match formula is an array formula, to be confirmed by pressing "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter" 3 keystrokes to enter it, or you could google "Excel array formula" for further detailing.

Comment: Edited to add details of other table. Office version is 365

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding a helper column where I check for presence of value in productName column. Then used a three criteria index match to get the final result